# Tree components of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph $G$ has $n$ vertices and $n-2$ edges and no isolated vertices (no connected component has only one vertex) we want to show that at least $2$ of its connected components are trees with at least $2$ vertices each.

I tried contradiction by supposing we have at most $1$ tree with at least $2$ vertices, which means either we had such a tree or not. In case we don't have such a tree, since the component is connected, I'm trying to get a contradiction by supposing that each of the components has at least $1$ cycle, but I haven't got further.

Answer (score 1):

a connected component on $c$ vertices has at least $c-1$ edges, with equality only if the component is a tree with at least $2$ vertices or is an isolated vertex. Therefore adding over all components we get the number of edges in $G$ is larger than or equal to $n-t$ where $t$ is the number of components that are trees with at least $2$ vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler characteristic $\chi(G)=V-E$ of a connected finite graph satisfies $\chi(G) \le 1$ with equality if and only if it is a tree.

For a disconnected finite graph $G$ with components $G=G_1 \cup \cdots \cup G_K$, we have
$$\chi(G) = \chi(G_1) + \cdots + \chi(G_K)
$$
Your graph $G$ has $\chi(G) = n - (n-2)=2 > 1$, so it is disconnected. In order for the above sum to be equal to $2$, at least two terms have to be $\ge 1$. But each term is $\le 1$. So at least two terms are $=1$. Thus, at least two of the components of $G$ are trees.